# Calculating the mean and variance of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, conditional-expectation, means, variance

I've been trying to solve the question below, but I am very confused. If anyone could lend a hand in helping me understand this problem by studying their solution, it would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Let X and Y be two possibly related/dependent random variables. Express the mean and the variance of X in terms of conditional means and conditional variances of X|Y.  I.e., find the functions f(.) and g(.) such that

1. $$​E[X] = f( E[X|Y] )$$
2. $$V[X] = g( E[X|Y], V[X|Y] )$$

Comment: Rather than posting problems whose very statement you do not understand, you will likely learn more (and more quickly) by asking questions that you do understand (though without knowing how to solve).  It is hard to see in "problem statement questions" of the type posted here any effort to approach the problem before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. By the [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation),

$$E[X] = E[E[X|Y]]$$

$f(X)$ then is $E[X]$

2. By the [law of total variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_variance),

$$Var[X] = E[Var[X|Y]] + Var[E[X|Y]]$$

$g(X, Y)$ then is $E[Y] + Var[X]$